# Enter random input selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I want to enter the string randomly(complete randomly) in a text field. for example: david, jan, mark.

So what I am trying to do is everytime I run the automation it randomly picks one of these names and enters it in the same text field.

I do not have code since I am starting it from scratch as that's a first step.

How will I be able to pick one of these names randomly?

Comment: You forgot to add a question to your statement of intent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer: You can use a name library and call the function that generates a name.

My recommendation is to create a new class called "TestUtils" or similar and use for example the Faker random name library.

All you need to do is to add the dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
<artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
<version>0.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In the class TestUtils use this code:

```
public static String getRandomString () {
    Faker faker = new Faker();
    return faker.hipster().word();
}
```

You can use pokemon names or Chuck Norris phrases, too, if you want.

To input the value into the field you just call the getRandomString() method. It could look like:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath")).sendKeys(TestUtils.getRandomString());